# Rails 3 : `require` within a generator

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, generator

I am writing a Rails 3 generator, but things get a bit complicated so I would like to extract some code to put it in a separate file.

So I create a file in the generator folder, and within my generator file, I put at the top:

```
require 'relative/path/to/my/code.rb'
```

But when I launch the generator, it tells me that it can't find the file.

```
activesupport-3.0.0.rc/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:219:in `require': no such file to load -- relative/path/to/my/code.rb (LoadError)
```

Does anybody know a work around ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends which Ruby version you are using.

In 1.8, it should work as you do. In 1.9 you should use `require_relative`.

You should also not add '.rb' at the end, this is not recommended.

The danger with a simple 'require' with a relative path is if this script is itself required by another, then the path will be relative to the first script called:

```
rootdir
  - main.rb
  - subdir1
    - second.rb
    - subdir11
      - third.rb
```

If main.rb is called, and then require second.rb (with `'subdir1/second'`), and then you want to require third.rb with `'subdir11/third.rb'`, it will not work.

You could be relative to the first script (`subdir1/subdir11/third.rb`), but that is not a good idea.
You could use `__FILE__` and then make it an absolute path:

> require File.expand_path('../subdir11/third.rb', **FILE**)

(the first .. is to get in the directory which contains the file) or

> require File.dirname(**FILE**) + '/subdir11/third.rb'

But the most common practice is to reference it from the rootdir.

In a gem, you can assume the rootdir will be in the `$LOAD_PATH` (or you can add it yourself).

In Rails you can use `require "#{RAILS_ROOT}/path"` (rails2) or

`require Rails.root.join('path')` (rails3)

Comment: Why is the '.rb' not recommended ? If not specified, the require method will anyways try to find the '.rb' file, or a '.so' or a '.dll'.

Comment: 'recommended' is probably not the good word, indeed. But this is common practice and I never saw any code using it, except when there is both a shared library and a ruby script with the same name.

Also, it looks pretty ugly ;)